# How to create nested namespace packages for setuptools distribution

Tags: python, namespaces, package, setuptools

I'm developing a python project that will have separately distributable parts.

I have been able to accomplish part of my goal by making a [namespace package](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/). I have "sub1" and "sub2", both in namespace "lvl1". I can pip install these in development mode using "pip install -e" or `python setup.py develop`. I can import them with `import lvl1.sub1` and `import lvl1.sub2`.

However, the project is massive and calls for **nested namespaces**. I want to `import lvl1.lvl2.sub1` and `import lvl1.lvl2.sub2`. So both subpackages are in the same namespace ("lvl2"), which is itself in a namespace ("lvl1").

Desired conceptual structure:

```
lvl1/
    lvl2/
        sub1/
            code.py
            more_code.py
            ...
        sub2/
            code.py
            ...
```

Is there a way to do this and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is more than one way. Please read [section "Nested namespace packages" in PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/#nested-namespace-packages).

In python >= 3.3, the easiest way to make nested namespace is to delete (do not include) file `__init__.py` in the specific folders ("lvl1" and "lvl2") in every distributable parts. In each of the `setup.py`, explicitly list all the packages in the deepest namespace.

"lvl1_part1/setup.py"

```
setup(
    name='lvl1_part1',
    ...
    zip_safe=False,
    packages=['lvl1.lvl2.sub1']
)
```

"lvl1_part2/setup.py"

```
setup(
    name='lvl1_part2',
    ...
    zip_safe=False,
    packages=['lvl1.lvl2.sub2']
)
```

The file structure for testing:

```
lvl1_part1/
           setup.py
           lvl1/
                lvl2/
                     sub1/
                          __init__.py
lvl1_part2/
           setup.py
           lvl1/
                lvl2/
                     sub2/
                          __init__.py
```

To make the above packages compatible to older python versions, please add the [`pkgutil` magic file](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#pkgutil-style-namespace-packages) to each of the "lvl1" and "lvl2" folders.

Credits: The example above is modified from https://github.com/pypa/sample-namespace-packages/tree/master/pkgutil